# RAID5 mdadm faulty / blk_update_request: I/O error

Tags: software-raid, mdadm, raid-5

I have five raw images of a server's disks (stored on one external HDD). Each of those disks contains two partitions which are `"Linux raid autodetect" (fd)` and are members of RAID1 (boot-related; 3 devices (2 active + 1 spare)) and **RAID5** (other data; 5 devices).

Having mapped devices using `kpartx` (or `losetup`, doesn't really matter) I run `mdadm` to assemble RAID arrays. RAID1 successfully assembled and I can mount it in a regular way. RAID5 is being assembled (actually "active", according to `/proc/mdstat`) but:

1. All devices are "**faulty**" and "**removed**";
2. I see additional errors in `dmesg` (`blk_update_request: I/O error, dev
   loop4, sector 16`) after which I get more errors (`md: super_written
   gets error=-5`; `md/raid:md0: Disk failure on loop5, disabling
   device.`);
3. I can't mount RAID5 array (fair enough).

I tried all suggestions I could find on the web:

1. Use `--force` key -> won't work;
2. Use `--create` and `--assume-clean` -> won't work;
3. Use `--zero-superblock` (which is similar to 2 ) -> won't work.
4. If check with `--examine` - all member devices are in **clean** state, checksum is **correct** and event numbers are **equal**.

As per 2 and 3 - it seems that I CAN'T write to those mapped devices. I `strace`'d `--zero-superblock` and, on `write()` syscall, I got `EPERM (Operation not permitted)`. Can't imagine what prevents me from writing to mapped devices (according to `lsblk --fpm` RAID5 device is writable `brw-rw----`).

Another peculiar detail. Above I mentioned that I get `I/O error` on sector **16**. I checked what's located at sector 16 (offset 8192 bytes) in every loop (mapped) RAID5 device. Appeared that it starts with magic number `0x6d746962` (ASCII: "`bitm`") - likely `bitmap` related:

```
00002000  62 69 74 6d 04 00 00 00  48 a7 15 94 56 79 23 ed  |bitm....H...Vy#.|<br/>
00002010  7d 7b 33 bc b9 f8 71 7a  d0 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  |}{3...qz........|<br/>
00002020  d0 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 b0 d8 0d 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

I'm not sure if it's related (at least I don't know how to play with bitmap while assembling array) but it's clear that system can't succeed with `blk_update_request` operation (likely it either lacks some rights or can't find what's needed).

I on purpose won't post wall of logs - please, let me know if it's needed. I'll enclose some info which describes situation better.

```
md0 : active raid5 dm-6[5](F) dm-8[4](F) dm-2[3](F) dm-4[2](F) dm-10[1](F)
      464609280 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/0] [_____]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

And here is from `--detail` output:

```
Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       2       0        0        2      removed
       4       0        0        4      removed
       6       0        0        6      removed
       8       0        0        8      removed

       1     252       10        -      faulty   /dev/dm-10
       2     252        2        -      faulty   /dev/dm-2
       3     252        4        -      faulty   /dev/dm-4
       4     252        8        -      faulty   /dev/dm-8
       5     252        6        -      faulty   /dev/dm-6
```

Today is a 3rd day in a row of my "tries harder"... I would appreciate any of your advices. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally, I managed to assemble the RAID5. As appeared, the problem was in the the following (I haven't mentioned it in my question). Disks' images I had were in E01 format, split to number of parts. Prior mapping partitions I used `ewfmount` (including `-X allow_root`) to "assemble" multiple E01s into one file. Turned out that **FUSE**, despite you see your images mounted as `RW`, somehow blocks them, making devices `read-only` (even if you edit `/etc/fuse.conf`).

One of my tries, while troubleshooting, was to export multiple E01s to five regular **dd**/**raw** formatted images and work with them directly, excluding `ewfmount` from the 'scheme".

Once export was completed I mapped raw disks using `kpartx`, and had been able to assemble RAID5 in a regular way with no problems.

Multiple `Operation not permitted` or `I/O error` problems were obvious and had to giveme a hint but I, due to unknown reasons, denied them (until I tried to modify some sectors on mapped devices with `dd` directly and failed).

That's it.